# 8-pin EATX12V on motherboard but new PSU does not support that

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

I have an ASUS H170 Pro Gaming Intel H170 motherboard (specs: https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1151/H170_PRO_GAMING/E10499_H170_PRO_GAMING_Guide_WEB_only.pdf?model=H170%20PRO%20GAMING - page 27):
[image]

[image]

I bought a new SilverStone DA850 Gold PSU (specs: https://www.silverstonetek.com/en/product/info/power-supplies/DA850Gold/):

[image]

My issue is the EATX12V 8-pin on the motherboard does not have an 8-pin motherboard on the PSU that I can connect to.

May I connect the EATX12V 8-pin from the motherboard into CPU/PCI-E on the PSU end?

Comment: It is the only connection you should use actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes - EATX12V 8-pin from the motherboard goes into the CPU/PCI-E on the PSU end.